# How to get the variable t-stat of multiple univariate OLS in statsmodels without looping?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, statsmodels

The below code works in getting the t-stats and r-squared for OLS I run.  However, I have millions of regressions to run and by looping, this is taking me ages.  Appreciated if alternative solutions are suggested.  Thanks.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.cumsum(np.ones(5))
df_y = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,30,40,50], 
                   "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], 
                   "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})
df_result = pd.DataFrame({"t-stats": np.ones(3)*np.nan, 
                          "r2": np.ones(3)*np.nan})
for i in range(0,df_y.shape[1]):
    y = df_y.iloc[:,i]
    results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
    df_result.loc[i, "t-stats"] = (results.params/results.bse).values
    df_result.loc[i, "r2"] = results.rsquared
```

Sorry, adding on to my questions.

What if there are missing values in y?  How this can be handled?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this with statsmodels since y must be a single variable.  If you really need performance here, you can easily write your own version using numpy. Assuming `x` never changes

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Assume y is n by m where m is 1,000,000, use 1,000 here for speed
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((20,1000)))
x = pd.DataFrame(sm.add_constant(np.random.standard_normal((20,3))))
_x = np.asarray(x)
_y = np.asarray(y)
b = np.linalg.lstsq(_x, _y, rcond=None)[0]
e = _y - _x @ b
err_var = (e**2).mean(0)
# correct formula depends if x has a constant, here I assume it does
r2 = 1.0 - err_var / ((_y - _y.mean(0))**2).mean(0)
xpxi = np.linalg.inv(_x.T@_x)
se = np.sqrt(np.diag(xpxi)[:,None]*err_var)
tstats = b / se
```

This approach is less robust than using statsmodels but will be an order of magnitude faster precisely because it avoids lots of checks, edge case protections, and calculating statistics you do not want.

On my machine this code runs in 1.9ms, so with 1,000,000 series it would take around 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the solution. In my case, y and x are both  a single variable and with a constant.

Comment: What if there are missing values in y?  How this can be handled?  Thanks

Comment: You usually need to drop these from both y and x before running the code.

Comment: so that can't be done in the above fashion as the missing values in each of the y are at different places.....

Comment: That is correct.  When you have missing values you need to select the correct subset of both y and x to get the correct results, so you effectively need to run the model in each dataset.